# Why would an empty class serve as the base class for several generic classes?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, generics, inheritance

I'm looking over some scripts from a Unity project called 2D GameKit, & I'm trying to learn from piecing together the purpose of each.  In one of them that serves as a mechanism for persistent storage, I noticed that several generic classes were derived from an empty base class.  Why?

Here is a sample of the code:

```
 public class Data
    {

    }


    public class Data<T> : Data
    {
        public T value;

        public Data(T value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }


    public class Data<T0, T1> : Data
    {
        public T0 value0;
        public T1 value1;

        public Data(T0 value0, T1 value1)
        {
            this.value0 = value0;
            this.value1 = value1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because author of the code decided that it is right/good solution. Even if you come up with specific classes the question likely will stay too broad/opinion based... ("why person X decided to do Y" is nearly impossibly to answer in concrete way, "what are benefits from deriving generics from a base class" is asking for a list and is too broad)

Comment: Probably so you can pass either type to generic methods that have a `where T : Data` constraint (or to any method that takes a `Data` type as an argument).

Answer (score 3):

So that you can check (know / compare) that a certain object is definitely data. If you don't have a base class, when you want to check if an object is certainly a type of data before processing it, you will need to compare with `Data<T>` AND `Data<T0, T1>` and also any other data types that is created in the future